# MacBook takes a long time to log in when VPN disconnects

Tags: macbook-pro, vpn, login

I use a VPN to connect to websites I use all day for work. Occasionally, I will lock my computer and leave it for a while (e.g. during lunch). When I return, it will often take several minutes to log in to my computer, whether with the password or fingerprint. When it finally does log in, a dialog immediately appears that says I have been disconnected from the VPN.

This dialog is not unusual, and I will occasionally get it if my internet has issues. I assume that while the MacBook is locked it slows things down or otherwise interferes with the VPN, so I'm not surprised that I get disconnected from the VPN. However, I don't know why that makes it take so long to log in.

Why does this happen? Is there anything I can do (short of disconnecting the VPN before locking, which would be annoying) to prevent this from happening?

Specs:

- MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)
- macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G3020)